# Meaning of exp{expression} in mathematical equations

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, kinematics

I was reading a paper by G.Newell 1964, and the paper's notation was different from the modern ones.

He postulated a law on car-following which dictates :

$$
    v_j(t) = \frac{dy_j(t)}{dt} = V_j - V_j exp\{-\lambda_jV^{-1}_j[y_{j-1}(t-\Delta)-y_j(t-\Delta)]\}$$

And I am not sure if :

$exp\{-\lambda_jV^{-1}_j[y_{j-1}(t-\Delta)-y_j(t-\Delta)]\}$

is supposed to mean :

$e^{-\lambda_jV^{-1}_j[y_{j-1}(t-\Delta)-y_j(t-\Delta)]}$

Or simply a differential equation named "exp"

Since back then, car following modeling was much more linear in its relations.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would assume it's $e^x$ unless there is a contradiction later.

Comment: It means the exponential function: $$e^\text{something complicated}$$ is harder to read than $$\text{exp}(\text{something complicated}).$$

Comment: Although it's very hard to be sure taken out of context, it is true that $\exp(X)$ is a widely used alternate expression for $e^X$. This is so even in modern writing, especially when the $X$ expression is so complicated that putting it into the tiny "superscript" font will negatively affect readability.

Comment: Thank you, I came to assume that too. I was interpreting it as a nonlinear equation in the sense that it was a quadratic function, since the plot of $V(.)$ in function of differentiated space $dx_j$ (not time) in the paper is a non-linear function that diverges gradually from a linear function. But it looks like $ e^{theExpressionInside} $ gives a similar plot.